# Read Barcode ID from SerialPort not giving the desired result

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce, barcode

I'm currently developing a bar-code reader application for an embedded WinCE device which has a built-in bar-code scanner in COM3 Serial Port. I wrote the following codes so that it detects every time a bar-code is scanned (when COM3 receives a data).

(VS2005: VB.NET for SmartDevice:Windows CE 5.0)

```
Private Sub sp1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
    Handles sp1.DataReceived

    Q.Enqueue(sp1.ReadExisting)
End Sub
```

And I use a timer to display the ID scanned.

```
SyncLock Q
    While Q.Count > 0
       barcodeLbl.Text &= Q.Dequeue
    End While
End SyncLock
```

The ID is displayed everytime I scan my bar-code. That works fine. However, I am not getting the correct ID in my barcodeLbl.Text. Instead I got something like: "F+)i+i~" when using **sp1.ReadExisting** and few ASCII numbers when I use **sp1.ReadChar** in the above code.

Here's what I found out:

"**F+)i+k~**" corresponds to "9920021101"

"**F+)i+i~**" corresponds to "9920021102"

"**F+)i+k~**" corresponds to "9920021103"

"**F+)i+m~**" corresponds to "9920021104"

(101 and 103 give the same result)

Now I just need my SerialPort to give me the correct ID. Been stuck at this for a day now. I will really appreciate me if anyone can pinpoint where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like it might be an encoding issue.  What's the barcode scanner device?

Comment: Don't ignore the ErrorReceived event, it tells you that there are basic problems like this.  You probably now get a framing error, you'd experiment with the Baudrate property next.

Comment: @Adrian Hi, it's a built-in Scantech device. (http://www.champtek.com/upfile/product_pdf/P_00000265_SK-50Specifications.pdf) - Imager Scanner. But I'm confused how 101 and 103 give the same codes.

+HansPassant I'm not really receiving any error. Framing error? Sorry, can you elaborate what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant Changing the BaudRate to 9600 works! Wow. Thanks a lot buddy! Should you have put it as an answer, I could have at least mark your answer. Thank you once again!